# Ruby on rails calculating total sum

Tags: ruby-on-rails

| id | tithe | offertory | pledge | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 120 | 230 | 280 | ??? |

I have a table like this and I want the total = tithe + offertory + pledge.
how do I write a query for this?

Comment: Is this the actual table? Total is actually a column? If that is the case I would just add a before_save to calculate the total `before_save :calculate_total; def calculate_total; self.total = [self.tithe,self.offertory,self.pledge].reduce(0.0) {|m,e| m + e.to_f}`. If the table does not include this column then you can create a method in the model `def total; @total ||= [self.tithe,self.offertory,self.pledge].reduce(0.0) {|m,e| m + e.to_f}` or a virtual attribute in the query `Record.select('records.*,records.tithe + records.offertory + records.pledge as total')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the use of sum:

```rb
Record.where(id: 1).sum('tithe + offertory + pledge')
```